# How to write an update query which sets a column to the sum of two other columns which are type varchar?

Tags: mysql

Here is what I have, the two columns to be added can be NULL by default:

```
UPDATE house SET TOTALTAX=IFNULL(MUNTAX,0)+IFNULL(SCHTAX,0) WHERE NNS_NO=542
```

This gives me 0 rows affected.  I verified the NNS number is correct, I don't really know what to try next.

Okay, I found out the columns MUNTAX AND SCHTAX are type varchar and not integers. For example, MUNTAX = "$7,725.00", SCHTAX = NULL  in this case.
So the question is now how to extract just the dollar value as an integer before calculating the sum and updating it as varchar (TOTALTAX is also varchar)?  Do I need a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you show the output of `SELECT * FROM house WHERE NNS_NO=542` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE house`? If you make any modifications to either of these queries before running them then please also show exactly what query you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ah I see you also want to turn the result back into a VARCHAR. Adding the $ sign back to the front should be easy with CONCAT(), but adding the commas back in would be tricky without writing a custom function. I probably don't need to tell you, but storing values like this as VARCHARs in the database isn't a good idea.

It ain't pretty, but something like this?

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM sum2;
+--------+--------+-------+
| a      | b      | total |
+--------+--------+-------+
| $1,000 | $2,000 |  NULL |
| $1,500 | NULL   |  NULL |
+--------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> UPDATE sum2 SET total= IFNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(a, '$', ''), ',', ''), 0) + IFNULL((REPLACE(REPLACE(b, '$', ''), ',', '')), 0);
Query OK, 2 row affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM sum2;
+--------+--------+-------+
| a      | b      | total |
+--------+--------+-------+
| $1,000 | $2,000 |  3000 |
| $1,500 | NULL   |  1500 |
+--------+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: I edited the details, please refresh the question - i basically have a problem to convert the cols from var char to integer, eliminating the $ sign to do so; then getting the sum; then converting the integer sum back to varchar as $x,xxx and updating the TOTALTAX col.

Answer (score 0):

try following query to check whether record is properly updated or not.
If its already updated they your query will give show 0 rows affected.

```
SELECT  TOTALTAX, MUNTAX, SCHTAX FROM house WHERE NNS_NO=542
```